# Unable to view history of branch deleted in github

Tags: git, github

I am unable to view history of deleted branch on GitHub. Could anyone please suggest steps to view my deleted branch .

I don’t have pull request for that branch , I am trying to view on GitHub console my deleted branch .

Comment: Did you have it locally before? You can go back in time using git reflog. Also you might be able to restore a deleted branch in the GitHub UI.

Answer (score 0):

once the pointer has moved, there is no memory that previous commits were on that branch. This was a hard concept for me to wrap my head around at first. Perhaps it's the name: "branch" makes me think of multiple nodes connected by
edges, but in Git, a branch is really only a moving pointer to a node.

1/ use  =>  `git log` => if it work it goes well that's fine

1*/ if not use this command and keep "enter" : `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate`

1**/ if not of the above go to your extensions in github account , you will search for **git graph**, download it and you gonna see the tree of github with all your branches and differences between every versions.